# Nested Queries not working in iOS sdk, but works fine in loopback explorer

Tags: ios, loopback

Currently I'm working on a project that gets values using iOS loopback sdk. Everything works by the book if its is one query.

But when nested query, like below, occurs it shows error

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"error":{"name":"Error","status":500,"message":"Relation \"relation\" is not defined for UserGroup model","stack":"Error: Relation \"relation\" is not defined for UserGroup model
```

The query is as below

```
NSDictionary *filterParams = @{
                                   @"where" : @{
                                           @"group_id" : self.groupDetails[@"groupId"]},
                                   @"include" : @[@"invitedusers",
                                                  @{
                                                      @"relation" : @"userstatus",
                                                      @"scope": @{
                                                              @"include":@[ @"useruploads" ]
                                                        }
                                                }]
                                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *filterParams = @{
                               @"where" : @{
                                       @"group_id" : self.groupDetails[@"groupId"]
                                       },
                               @"include" : @[ @"invitedusers",
                                               @{
                                                   @"userstatus" : @"useruploads"
                                                   }
                                               ]
                               };
```

You can refer to this also: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html